# Why update-java-alternatives -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto does not update jexec?

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, update-alternatives

Ubuntu 22.04.2:

I installed java-17-amazon-corretto and did the update-java-alternatives but I got an error compiling my project. Last time I had to fix the links that were not updated, (java 11 vs javac 8).

If I go under `/etc/alternatives` and do `ls -la |grep java` I see different configuration for links:

```
javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah
jjs -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs
javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/bin/javac
```

I guessed these executable are not distributed anymore with new JVM.

But this one:

`jexec -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec`

was not updated to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/lib/jexec`

When I do `sudo update-alternatives --list jexec` I get only this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jexec
```

How come this one was not updated and not visible for the update-alternatives binary?

Is there a better way to check all these 97 links or do I fix them manually?

After manual check there is also `jfr` with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the packaging of java-17-amazon-corretto. I installed on a test Ubuntu 22.04 system and had the same issues.

However when I installed openjdk-17-jdk from Ubuntu's repositories, all the correct alternatives were created.

```
apt install openjdk-17-jdk

update-java-alternatives -s java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64
```